# Writing a blank instead of an integer in Fortran

Tags: fortran, integer, character

I have a few 110-element vectors. They sometimes have a value from `0` to `9`, but their default value is `-1`. I'd like to print a blank if a cell's value is  `-1`; print their value otherwise.

I'm printing several things in an output line so I can't use an `if` with two `write`s. Passing the values to a `character` vector worked but I can't help but think there must be a better way.

My attempt:

```
program integer_print_blank_test
implicit none

integer, dimension(9)          :: longint
character(len=3), dimension(9) :: longchar
integer                        :: i, j

do i = 0, 2
write(*,*) (longint(3*i+j), j = 1, 3)
end do

longint = -1

longint(1) = 1
longint(4) = 3
longint(9) = 7

write(*,*) "longint"
do i = 0, 2
write(*,*) (longint(3*i+j), j = 1, 3)
end do

do i = 1, 9
write(longchar(i),"(I3)") longint(i)
end do

write(*,*) "longchar"
do i = 0, 2
write(*,*) (longchar(3*i+j), j = 1, 3)
end do

write(*,*) "only positives in longchar"
longchar = " "

do i = 1, 9
  if (longint(i) > -1) then
    write(longchar(i),"(I3)") longint(i)
  end if
end do

do i = 0, 2
write(*,*) (longchar(3*i+j), j = 1, 3)
end do

end program integer_print_blank_test
```

Answer (score 3):

You might think this is a better way.  Define a function such as

```
  ELEMENTAL FUNCTION borf(int) RESULT(str)
    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: int
    CHARACTER(len=2) :: str
    str = '  '
    IF (int>-1) WRITE(str,'(i2)') int
  END FUNCTION borf
```

and use it like this

```
  WRITE(*,*) borf(longint)
```

Comment: How do I declare the function?

Comment: Whaddya mean *How do I declare the function?* ?  You copy what I wrote into your source file (in the right place of course) and compile it all up.  If you don't know how to do that, you should probably ask another question, it's not something I could teach you in comments.